# Area of the square is $16$ square units. Midpoint of the sides of the square are $a,b,c,d$. Then what is the area of the shaded part?

Tags: geometry

Area of the square is $16$ square units. Midpoint of the sides of the square are $a,b,c,d$. Then what is the area of the shaded part?

[image]

Comment: Please edit the question to include your own thoughts on the problem.  What have you tried?  Where are you stuck?

Answer (score 3):

Hint

(assuming the four arcs are symmetric - the diagram does not seem precise and the midpoints are not in the middle)

[image]